# How to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=3}^ \infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)))^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, summation, numerical-methods

I saw this problem : Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=3}^ \infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)(\ln(\ln(n)))^2}$ converges, this is an easy problem could be proved using Cauchy condensation test twice.

$$\sum_{n=3}^ \infty \frac{2^n}{2^n n\ln(2)(\ln(n \ln(2)))^2}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(2)(\ln(n \ln(2)))^2} $$
and
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{2^n}{2^n (\ln(2^n \ln(2)))^2}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{ n^2(\ln( \ln(2)))^2} $$ which converges.

---

I because curios what is the limit of this sum ? I tried every method I know but all of them lead to  nothing.

Since it might be impossible to find the exact sum of this series I want to ask for a numerical approximation for this sum.

Comment: Except for a few very special cases, most of the time we have no idea how to compute the sum of a series. In most cases we can only say whether the series converges. Of course, if we know that there is convergence, there are also many numerical methods to approximate the sum, but not to actually compute it.

Comment: @Mark I edited the question to include numerical approximation as an answer

Comment: Let me explain why even numerical approximations may disappoint you. You can also prove convergence by changing to an integral, then substituting $x=\ln\ln n$. Doing so tells us a partial sum will have an error $\sim 1/x=1/(\ln\ln n)$, which is extremely slow convergence. Therefore, any numerical method needs either [series acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) or [a more precise integral/sum comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula).

Answer (score 2):

In general we can approximate a sum $S=\sum_{i=m}^n f(i)$ by an integral $I=\int_m^n f(x)dx$, more precisely for $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $f(x)=1/(x\log(x)(\log\log(x))^2)$ we have $f(n)\geq f(x)\geq f(n+1)$ and integrating this inequality we obtain
\begin{align}
0&\leq \sum_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)-\int_{n_0}^\infty f(x)dx\leq f(n_0) \\
0&\leq\sum_{n=n_0}^\infty f(n)-\frac 1{\log\log(n_0)}\leq f(n_0).
\end{align}
People like to joke that iterated log is a constant, and it is almost true. So you have to account for the term that comes from the integral to get decent bounds. For $n_0=1000$ we get
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac 1{n\log(n)(\log\log(n))^2}\approx\sum_{n=3}^{n_0}\frac 1{n\log(n)(\log\log(n))^2}+\frac 1{\log\log(n_0)}=38.40678\ldots$$
with an error of magnitude less than $f(n_0)=0.0000387...$.

Comment: Simply validating based on the comment of @J.G above. A simple extrapolation based on the form $S_n = S + C/\log\log n$, using $n = 10,000, 20,000$, yields 38.4067866.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a complete answer, but maybe it helps..**

Here, have some derivatives:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log x = \frac{1}{x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log\log x = \frac{1}{x\log x}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{\log\log x} = \frac{-1}{x\log x(\log\log x)^2}$$

Therefore, take
$$F(x) = -\frac{1}{\log\log x}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x\log x(\log\log x)^2}$$

Where, $F'(x) = f(x)$. The sum can be re-written as: $\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n)$, and because $f(x)$ is continuous and monotone decreasing for $x\ge 3$, one can use integral comparison:
$$
\int_3^\infty f(x)dx\le\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n)\le f(3) + \int_3^\infty f(x)dx
$$
$$
F(\infty) - F(3)\le\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n) \le F(\infty) - F(3) + f(3)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{\log\log 3}\le\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n) \le \frac{1}{\log(\log 3)} + \frac{1}{3\log 3(\log\log 3)}
$$
$$
\left|\sum_{n=3}^\infty f(n) - \frac{1}{\log(\log 3)}\right|\le\frac{1}{3\log 3(\log\log 3)}
$$

I think you can get a better approximation with arbitrary precision, by continuing this calculation using the [Euler-Maclaurin Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Answer (score 0):

Using Python script:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 50
limit = 1000
summ = 0
for n in range(3, limit):
    summ += Decimal(1)/(Decimal(n)*Decimal(n).ln()* (Decimal(n).ln().ln())**2)
print(summ)
```

we can guess the limit is around `38`, by increasing `limit` value.

For limit=1000 we have ~37.89
For limit=10000 we have ~37.96